# Dynamic Build ws Request in Scala Play

Tags: scala, playframework

In my Play application, I build a request like this:

```
val a = 10    
val b = 10
val req = ws.url(URL)
          .withHeaders("Accept" -> "application/json")
          .withQueryString("a" -> a, "b" -> b)
          .withRequestTimeout(Duration.Inf)
```

What I am trying to do is to build the Query String from a map, which is throwing the following error:

```
val c = Map("a" -> a, "b" -> b)
val req = ws.url(URL)
    .withHeaders("Accept" -> "application/json")
    .withQueryString(c.toSeq)
    .withRequestTimeout(Duration.Inf)
```

I get a type mismatch error:

> Expected(String, String), actual: Seq[(String,any)]

Comment: you haven't specified the type of request also, like in the end .get or .post

Comment: Also converting the above Map toSeq should give you Seq[(String, Int)]

Comment: Like this tuple, also can you mention what does ur endpoint look like, it depends on that as well

Comment: yea its get request and i am calling the request in some other function. I am just building the request here.

Comment: Ohk and what time of input does ur get request requires ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
.withQueryString(c.toSeq : _*)
```

I believe the method takes varargs.

You'll probably also need to turn the values into a `Seq[String]`:

```
.withQueryString(c.mapValues(v => Seq(v.toString)).toSeq : _*)
```

Maybe?

Comment: @Alvaro first one did the job. Thanks (Y)